# webjars 3.3.1 jquery.min.js different from CDN's 3.3.1 jquery.min.js; mismatching Subresource Integrity SRI

Tags: jquery, webjars, subresource-integrity

I noticed that 3.3.1 jquery.min.js is different in my webjar and on the CDN. They had diffferent SRIs. I investigated it and noticed that files are not exactly binary equivalent.

Given that SRI is important:
**- How come the files can be different?**

Here is how to replicate:

```
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.jar
wget https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
unzip jquery-3.3.1.jar
ls -la META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js ./jquery.min.js
diff META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js ./jquery.min.js
```

Will get you (different size):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someuser someuser 86927 Jan 20 18:03 ./jquery.min.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someuser someuser 86962 Jan 23 07:12 META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
```

And diff will show additional line:

```
< //# sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Can you file a bug at: https://github.com/webjars/jquery ?

Comment: @James Ward thanks. I filed it.